# OpenGL - Why are my objects transparent?

Tags: opengl, transparency

I am trying to make a motorcycle with primitive shapes. For some reason, the shapes that I have made are see-through. I am not specifying any alpha anywhere; here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
static int isWire = 0; // Is wireframe?
static int distance = 10;
static float angleH = 0;
static float angleV = 0;

static float R = 2.0; // Radius of hemisphere.
static int p = 4; // Number of longitudinal slices.
static int q = 6; // Number of latitudinal slices.

#define PI 3.14159265358979324

static unsigned int pipe, seat, cover, wheel, wheelCenter, cycles; // parts of the motorcycle to make as display lists.
GLUquadricObj *cylinder;

void drawCoordinates();
void drawMotorcycle();
void drawTrailer();
void drawHemisphere();
void drawCylinder(float x, float y, float z);
void drawHandle(float x, float y, float z);
void drawLight();
void drawBase();
void setup();

void display () {

    /* clear window */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(distance*cos(angleH), distance*cos(angleV), distance*sin(angleH), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    /* future matrix manipulations should affect the modelview matrix */
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    if (isWire) glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); else glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glPushMatrix();

        drawCoordinates();

        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);   // Move the motorcycle around the world space
            drawMotorcycle();
            drawTrailer();
        glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();

    /* flush drawing routines to the window */
    glFlush();
}

void drawCoordinates()
{
    /***************** DRAW AXIS *****************/
    glPushMatrix();
        GLUquadricObj *xAxis; 
        xAxis=gluNewQuadric();
        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glRotatef(-90, 0, 1, 0);
        gluCylinder(xAxis,0.05,0.05,1,5,5); 
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        GLUquadricObj *yAxis; 
        yAxis=gluNewQuadric();
        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
        gluCylinder(yAxis,0.05,0.05,1,5,5); 
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        GLUquadricObj *zAxis; 
        zAxis=gluNewQuadric();
        glColor3f(0,0,1);
        gluCylinder(zAxis,0.05,0.05,1,5,5); 
    glPopMatrix();
    /***************** END OF DRAW AXIS *****************/
}

void drawMotorcycle()
{
    //DRAW ENGINE
    glPushMatrix();
        //drawCoordinates();
        glColor3f(.6, 0, 0);
        glScalef(1.4, 0.8, 1.0);
        glutSolidSphere(1,8,8);
        glPushMatrix();
            //drawCoordinates();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW PIPES UNDER ENGINE
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(80, 0, 1, 0);
        glTranslatef(0.5, 1.0, -1.5);
        glCallList(pipe);
        glTranslatef(0.0, -2.0, 0.0);
        glCallList(pipe);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW SEAT
    glPushMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(15, 0, 0, 1);
            glTranslatef(-2.0, -0.4, 0.0);
            glScalef(2.0, 0.2, 1.2);
            glCallList(seat);
        glPopMatrix();

        //DRAW BACK SEAT
        glRotatef(-40, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(-2.3, -2.8, 0.0);
        glScalef(2.0, 0.2, 1.2);
        glCallList(seat);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW FRONT PLATE
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(120, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(0.8, -1.3, 0.0);
        glScalef(2.0, 0.2, 1.35);
        glColor3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
        glutSolidCube(1);
        glPushMatrix();
            //drawCoordinates();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW FRONT PIPES
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(-30, 0, 1, 0);
        glTranslatef(1.3, -0.9, -5.7);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 2.5);
        glCallList(pipe);
        glTranslatef(0.0, 1.7, 0.0);
        glCallList(pipe);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW WHEEL COVERS
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(3.5, -3.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
        glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
        glCallList(cover);
        glTranslatef(-5.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-100, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(-8.5, 0.2, 0.0);
        glCallList(cover);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW WHEELS
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(3.9, -4.1, 0.0);
        glCallList(wheel);
        glTranslatef(-9.2, 2.0, 0.0);
        glCallList(wheel);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW WHEEL CENTER PIECES
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(3.9, -4.1, 0.0);
        glCallList(wheelCenter);
        glTranslatef(-9.2, 2.0, 0.0);
        glCallList(wheelCenter);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW CYCLES AROUND WHEELS
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(3.9, -4.1, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
            glPushMatrix();
                glCallList(cycles);
            glPopMatrix();
        }

        glTranslatef(-9.2, 0.0, 2.0);

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
            glPushMatrix();
                glCallList(cycles);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW HANDLE BARS
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.2, 2.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-45, 1, 0, 0);
        glScalef(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
        glCallList(pipe);
        glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
        glCallList(pipe);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW LIGHT
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
        //glScalef(1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
        glutSolidSphere(0.5, 5, 5);
        glPushMatrix();
            //drawCoordinates();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW BASE
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glScalef(3.5, 1.5, 1.0);
        glTranslatef(-0.4, -1.0, 0.0);
        glColor3f(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
        glutSolidCube(1);
    glPopMatrix();

    //GAS TANK
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(2.5, 1.0, 0.8);
        glTranslatef(-0.8, -1.7, -1.4);
        glCallList(pipe);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void drawTrailer()
{
    //DRAW BODY
    glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.3);
        glScalef(2.0, 2.5, 1.5);
        glTranslatef(-4.5, -0.5, 0.0);
        glutSolidCube(1);
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW WHEELS
    glPushMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
            glScalef(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
            glTranslatef(-12.0, -1.5, 2.0);
            glCallList(wheel);
            glCallList(wheelCenter);

            glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
            for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            {
                glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                    glCallList(cycles);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
            glScalef(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
            glTranslatef(-12.0, -1.5, -2.0);
            glCallList(wheel);
            glCallList(wheelCenter);

            glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
            for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            {
                glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
                glPushMatrix();
                    glCallList(cycles);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    //DRAW CONNECTION TO MOTORCYCLE
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
        glTranslatef(0.0, -1.0, -8.0);
        glCallList(pipe);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void drawHemisphere()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < q; j++)
    {
        // One latitudinal triangle strip.
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for(int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
        {
            glVertex3f( R * cos( (float)(j+1)/q * PI/2.0 ) * cos( 2.0 * (float)i/p * PI ),
            R * sin( (float)(j+1)/q * PI/2.0 ),
            R * cos( (float)(j+1)/q * PI/2.0 ) * sin( 2.0 * (float)i/p * PI ) );
            glVertex3f( R * cos( (float)j/q * PI/2.0 ) * cos( 2.0 * (float)i/p * PI ),
            R * sin( (float)j/q * PI/2.0 ),
            R * cos( (float)j/q * PI/2.0 ) * sin( 2.0 * (float)i/p * PI ) );         
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{

    // (Window of width = zero is not possible).
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio = 1.0* w / h;

    // Reset the coordinate system before modifying
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Set the correct perspective.
    gluPerspective(90,ratio,-1,1);
}


// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key) 
   {
    case 'c' : distance = 10; angleH=0; angleV=0.0; break;
    case 'C' : distance = 10; angleH=0; angleV=0.0; break;
    case 'f': distance = (distance == 4)? 4:distance-1; break;
    case 'F': distance = (distance == 4)? 4:distance-1; break;
    case 'b': distance = (distance == 20)? 20:distance+1; break;
    case 'B': distance = (distance == 20)? 20:distance+1; break;
    case 'w': if (isWire == 0) isWire = 1; else isWire = 0; break;
    case 'W': if (isWire == 0) isWire = 1; else isWire = 0; break;
    //case 27: exit(0); break;
    default: break;
   }
}

void specialKeyboard(int key, int x, int y) {
   switch (key)
   {
       case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
      angleH -= .2;
      break;
   case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
      angleH += .2;
      break;
   case GLUT_KEY_UP:
       angleV += .2;
      break;

   case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
       angleV -= .2;
      break;
   }

}

void update(void){
   glutPostRedisplay();
}

void setup()
{
    // PARTS
    pipe = glGenLists(1);
    seat = glGenLists(1);
    cover = glGenLists(1);
    wheel = glGenLists(1);
    wheelCenter = glGenLists(1);
    cycles = glGenLists(1);

    glNewList(pipe, GL_COMPILE);   // Any cylinder on the motorcycle
        GLUquadricObj *cylinder; 
        cylinder=gluNewQuadric();
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(.5,.5,.5);
            gluCylinder(cylinder,0.2,0.2,3,5,5);
                glPushMatrix();
                    //drawCoordinates();
                glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();

    glNewList(seat, GL_COMPILE);
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(0.5, 0.35, 0.05);
            glutSolidCube(1);
                glPushMatrix();
                    //drawCoordinates();
                glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();

    glNewList(cover, GL_COMPILE);
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
            drawHemisphere();
                glPushMatrix();
                    //drawCoordinates();
                glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();

    glNewList(wheel, GL_COMPILE);
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
            glutSolidTorus(0.2, 1.2, 20, 20);
                glPushMatrix();
                    //drawCoordinates();
                glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();

    glNewList(wheelCenter, GL_COMPILE);
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(0.4, 0.5, 0.5);
            glScalef(1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
            glutSolidSphere(0.8, 5, 5);
                glPushMatrix();
                    //drawCoordinates();
                glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();

    glNewList(cycles, GL_COMPILE);
        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        glScalef(0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
        cylinder=gluNewQuadric();
        gluCylinder(cylinder,0.5,0.5,5,15,5);
    glEndList();
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    /* initialize GLUT, using any commandline parameters passed to the 
       program */
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    /* setup the size, position, and display mode for new windows */
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );

    /* create and set up a window */
    glutCreateWindow("Motorcycle");
    setup(); // Build all the display lists, ready to use

    glutIdleFunc(update);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);

    /* set up depth-buffering */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    /* background color */
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    /* tell GLUT to wait for events */
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

You can rotate the camera with the arrow keys to see that the objects are see through. How can I fix this?  Is there anything else I can do to improve my code?

Comment: How about a screenshot? or explicitly calling gl.disable(BLEND); or setting blending function to SET.

Comment: Are you sure they are (semi) transparent? Maybe the quadrics are solid but pointed the wrong way? Have yoo tried calling gluQuadricOrientation() to make sure the normals point out? (I'm assuming isWire == true is not what you're talking about here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `reshape()`:

```
// Set the correct perspective.
gluPerspective(90,ratio,-1,1);
```

I'm guessing you transliterated parameters from a `glOrtho()` call, where a negative `zNear` is perfectly legitimate.

[From the `gluPerspective()` docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml#parameters):

> zNear: Specifies the distance from the viewer to the near clipping plane **(always positive)**.

Try this:

```
gluPerspective(90,ratio,1,100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); to your initialization function.

Comment: Well, actually this is drawing state and should be put into the display function right before where it's needed. But yes, a not enable depth test most likely is the culprit.

Comment: nevermind, I see that you have it, just in the wrong spot. Move it up before you start drawing the objects.